# Android: Adding libraries through gradle with external repositories

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to import this library:

```
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2822
```

The instructions say:

```
The following goes in your module's build.gradle file:

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {

    // ... other dependencies here

     dependencies {
            compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'
     }
}
```

So I added to my app gradle the dependency (last line):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amazon.mysampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'

}
```

Then added the repository to my top level all projects gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'


    }
}
```

But it is not working I am getting the error:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2] on repository container.
```

I am obviously not writing my gradle file correctly but not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with removing repository from top level all projects gradle file like below...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Also you need to add `maven` url inside `repositories` to your app gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
}  

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amazon.mysampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'

}
```

Comment: Hi @Priyank thank for your response. Still the same error when I remove the top level line I added.

Comment: @NicholasMuir: Remove the `compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'` from the top-level `build.gradle` file, as is demonstrated in the first code listing in this answer. That `compile` statement is what your error message is complaining about, because `compile` statements do not go in `repositories` closures.

Comment: @Priyank, As I said. I removed that . It gives me a new error failed to resolve com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:1.0.2. Can you please try and import it to a project to see what I mean.

Comment: As per link suggestion, try with `compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'`. Instead of `1.0.2` try with `v1.0.2`.

Comment: There was also a spelling mistake in the copied and pasted info. But you answer was right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a very simple error:
Try removing the v from v1.0.2

So, instead of

`compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'`

try this:

`compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:1.0.2'`

I'm not sure if that's the issue, but you can give it a try.

**EDIT**: You also have to add jitpack to your repositories. If you look at the instructions, you can see it contains this:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

So add that to your gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried making all the changes you suggested. I also tried removing the v on each of them one by one and for both of them with and without your changes to make sure I covered all possible combinations and that has not worked.